# Пахнет ли графом здесь?

Tags: графы, дискретная-математика

Всем привет!
Неориентированный граф с четырьмя вершинами: a, b, c, d deg(a)=1, deg(b)=2, deg(c)=3, deg(d)=4 
возможно или нет?
(нет, то почему?)

deg - degree (степень)

Comment: Очень пахнет!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ну если допускаются кратные ребра, то почему нет-то. (a,d), (b,d), (b,c), (c,d), (c,d).